# Triac Control of Capacitive Load

Tags: triac

I'm using the circuit schematic shown to control an LED driver while measuring its input power. Input voltages range between 120-300VAC, and the optotriac is controlled with a digital IO pin on an Arduino Uno. [Triac](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/stmicroelectronics/t3035h-8g/?qs=lc2O%252bfHJPVbkDL0xbUPqZg%3D%3D&countrycode=US&currencycode=USD) and [optotriac](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/vishay/vot8026ad/?qs=0lSvoLzn4L%252bvKhngl6GZAw%3D%3D&countrycode=US&currencycode=USD) datasheets can be found in their hyperlinks. The input voltages are coming from a programmable AC Source (Adaptive Power FC205), so any anomalies on the waveforms seen are probably not due to issues with the source voltage.

When turning on the triac to power the LED driver we're noticing ripple waveforms at the point noted AO (see attached scope photo). I'm curious what could potentially fix this issue (figure adding a capacitor), but do not want to add a larger RC Snubber as this will go on a space-constrained PCB. This is my first time using Triacs, so I'm curious to see if anyone on this forum knows how to address the issue in a simple fashion.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Why do yo need two triacs in series? 2. Where is the capacitve load  as stated in the title? 3. What is the scope trace representing?

Comment: Great questions: 1) I need unobstructed access to the Neutral wire of the LED Driver before it gets powered to perform a resistance measurement.  2) capacitive load is placed between ‘LED_Driver’ and pin 1 of the bottom triac. Scope is the voltage waveform at pinA0 with 120VAC supplied to the circuit